# Why res.send( string ) download a file

Tags: node.js, express

I have an app where I want to render static html with express.

I know about `res.sendFile()` but that is not what I want to use. I want to load my files using `fs` and send them using `res.send()`

I do something like this :

```
fileFoo = fs.readFileSync('./html/foo.html', 'utf-8');
fileBar = fs.readFileSync('./html/bar.html', 'utf-8');

app = express()
app.get('/foo', (req, res) => res.send(fileFoo));
app.get('/foo/bar', (req, res) => res.send(fileBar));
```

With 2 very simple html files
foo.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>FOO</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>FOO</h1>
        <a href="/foo/bar">bar</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

bar.html

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>BAR</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>BAR</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I go to `/foo` I got a HTML rendered.
If I click on `bar` I do not get a new HTML page rendered but I got a file "bar" with no extension downloaded. The file of course content the HTML page.

What is happening ?

UPDATE :

I am actually using a router, not direct `app`.
And I think this 'download' occure only when I try to reach

```
router.get('/', (res, req) => res.send(fileBar));
```

Comment: why dont you change your router to `router.get('/foo/bar', (res, req) => res.render(fileBar));` and remove this `app.get('/foo/bar', (req, res) => res.send(fileBar));` from app.js?

Comment: Please refer to https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.render

Comment: Thanks you for your replies. I know about `render` system in express, but I am working on a Framework built around express, and for test purpose I want to use res.send, What i can't understand is that it is working fine for every one of my other routes, even if I use bar.html in it. But with the root `/` of my router it is downloading a file ...

Comment: I tried your code, it's fine for me, I got both html not download file. Do you have others settings about path? Does it happen in different browsers?

Comment: Hi @JackYu. I tried rewrite some of the code and it is working fine.
I get back on the code and empty the navigator cache and it is working.
I guess it was about previous test I was doing and cache. But not sure how it works.
Any way it is solved know, thanks for the help